# await self.disconnect(message["code"]) TypeError: ChatConsumer.disconnect() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, json, django, django-channels, django-channels-presence

**consumers.py**

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
# from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name ='chat_%s' % self.room_name

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )
```

**routing.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from room import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns=[
    path('ws/<str:room_name>/',consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

import room.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangochat.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http":get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket":AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            room.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

**error:**

```
Exception inside application: ChatConsumer.disconnect() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 263, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\auth.py", line 185, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 150, in __call__
    return await application(
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 94, in app
    return await consumer(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 58, in __call__
    await await_many_dispatch(
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\utils.py", line 51, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 73, in dispatch
    await handler(message)
  File "C:\Users\dines\Desktop\trying_again\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 238, in websocket_disconnect
    await self.disconnect(message["code"])
TypeError: ChatConsumer.disconnect() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am doing a chat application using the django channels
I do not know much about this channels or chat in django,
I followed one  video in doing this, I done as everything correct as guided in the video, but I am struggling with this from very long time,
I have searched and done as much as I can to solve that, but I didn't.
If any know about this please help me...

Answer (score 3):

The method signature of [`AsyncWebsocketConsumer.disconnect`](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/3.0.5/channels/generic/websocket.py#L241) that `ChatConsumer.disconnect` overrides is such that it is invoked with a message code when the websocket is closed.

Your implementation of the method override ought to be as follow:

```py
    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much  bro, 
I am just struggling with this from past one week,
Thanks a lot,